# ncview: Specify and correct displayed variable range

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

I created a netcdf file with python 3.6 and the netCDF4 module. Everything works fine *except for one variable* when displayed by the visual browser ncview. This variable ranges from 0 to 1000, but the displayed range remains near 0 and image is satured. Others variables are correctly plotted with the same piece of code.

What might be the cause of the problem?

I use to store data as packed data. Packed data are stored in a netCDF file by limiting precision and using a smaller data type than the original data, for example, packing double-precision (64-bit) values into short (16-bit) integers

My code:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset  
import numpy as np
....
nc_fid = Dataset(fname, 'w', clobber=True, format='NETCDF4')
....
nc_var = nc_fid.createVariable('Test', 'i2', ('time', 'Y', 'X'))

pack_range = np.array([-32766,32767], dtype=np.int16)
data_range = np.array([np.min(MyVar), np.max(MyVar)], dtype=np.float32)
pr = np.float32(pack_range)
dr = data_range
off = ((dr[0]*pr[1])-(dr[1]*pr[0]))/(pr[1]-pr[0])
fac = (dr[1]-dr[0])/(pr[1]-pr[0])

off, fac = calc_scale(var['dirN'] 
nc_var.setncatts({'scale_factor': fac,\
                    'add_offset': off,\
                    '_FillValue': np.int16(-32767),\
                    'missing_value': np.int16(-32767) })
nc_var[:] = MyVar
nc_fid.close()
```

I uploaded a short version of the file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11Adszwbr4gBWTASU0ZmhlfkypkC7qOHd/view?usp=sharing%22%3Efile%3C/a%3E).

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Can you share some or all of the netcdf file? That will help diagnose the issue on our end.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to reproduce this behavior with a minimal example. I uploaded a sample file showing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dirN variable in your netcdf sample file has *many* -32766 values and ncview is been get confused when it's computing min and max values.

Change the default ncview strategy to compute min and max by using:

```
 $ ncview -minmax all Sample.nc
```

Comment: So from what I understand, It's a default coming from ncview, not to the code which generated the file. ncview computed its min/max values with the first timestamp (with only 0 values) instead of the whole timeline.